# Java JInternalFrame on creation all overlapping

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java Swing App which adds JInternalPanes on button click into a JDesktopPane. However, every time I add a new JInternalPane to the DesktopPane, they all are overlapping and I always have to move the newest one to the side in order to see the previous one again.

Is there any way I can set the position of the newest one slightly to the right of the previous one?

I came up with this workaround but this just looks weird and there is probably a better alternative.

```
  public void createMarket() {
        this.appWindow.getDesktopPane().add(new Market(this.restClient, this.websocketClient, this.appWindow.getSymbolTextField().getText(), this.appWindow.getSelectedInterval()));

        if (this.appWindow.getDesktopPane().getAllFrames().length > 1) {
            JInternalFrame previousFrame = this.appWindow.getDesktopPane().getAllFrames()[this.appWindow.getDesktopPane().getAllFrames().length - 2];
            this.appWindow.getDesktopPane().getAllFrames()[this.appWindow.getDesktopPane().getAllFrames().length - 1].setLocation((int)(previousFrame.getLocation().getX() + 100), (int)(previousFrame.getLocation().getY()+100));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make a `DesktopLayoutManager`  - `JDesktopPane` extends `JLayeredPane`, these components, by design, do not use a layout manager by default, so you are completely responsible for managing the layout of the components

Answer (score 2):

There is no code in the Java platform that would tile or cascade JInternalFrames - you will have to write that yourself.

Here is some example of cascading internal frames:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JDesktopPaneCascadeDemo.htm

Note that the frames are placed using setBounds(). For tiling them, you'd have to check how many there are, decide about the amount of rows and columns, calculate the coordinates and call setBounds() again.